# How to drive a 360 degree rotating servo from ESP8266

Tags: arduino, servo, esp8266

I am building a project in which I have hacked a servo motor to rotate continuously in either direction. This means that I need to cut power to the motor when not in use via the ESP. I need to drive this motor from a ESP8266 but I am having trouble in interfacing it. I have wired up the same as shown in the diagram. The issue I am facing is that in clockwise direction it works perfectly fine while in the anticlockwise direction it jitters and in unable to rotate. If I supply the power to the servo directly (and not via ESP) then all works fine in both directions. I measured the current it draws and I can see that in tries to draw much more current in the anticlockwise direction (~170mA) and maybe because of that it is not able to move. I tried replacing transistor BC548 with another transistor with higher Ic (~200mA) but I still get the same result. Then I put a 220uF cap across the motor and then it works fine although it still jitters for a sec or two. Although it works with the capacitor, I still feel there is something fundamental I am missing here.

Another point to note is I don't want to use a lot of components as the space where I will install this is small and so I am avoiding a relay (which is a lot simpler to wire though).

Can somebody pl guide me on this?

I think my code itself may not be relevant here, the only thing I would like to mention is that I am using `myservo.write(180)` for clockwise rotation and `myservo.write(0)` for anticlockwise.

[image]

Comment: That servo normally has 3 wires but the schematic you've posted only shows 2. Have you hacked all of the guts out of the servo so that its really just a geared motor or is there something else you've neglected to mention?

Comment: Typically, hacked servos still use the PWM input to control direction and speed - you still need all three wires to operate them.  You show only two wires, and seem to be using the PWM output of the ESP8266 to control power to the servo.  Where did the PWM input of the servo go?

Comment: sorry, I omitted the same for brevity. Yes I have that wire going into the motor. I'll update eh diagram to be clear.

Comment: [TowerPro MG995 - Continuous rotation 360° Metal Gear Servo Motor](https://robu.in/product/towerpro-mg995-continuous-rotation-360-metal-gear-servo-motor-9-2kg/) "IMP NOTE :- THIS SERVO DRAWS HIGH CURRENT WHILE OPERATION (UP TO 2AMP IN STALL) "

Answer (score 1):

I actually found another (simpler) way to do the same thing. Instead of using hardware to control the switching ON/OFF of the servo, I figured out that it is also possible to do the same via software. I am now using detach() to stop the servo when not required while directly powering the servo at all times. It draws about 6mA current when not working which is okay for my use as my stuff is not battery powered.
But in case somebody else has a solution to doing this via hardware, pl do share.

Comment: Unless you need the lowest possible idle power consumption this is the best solution.